# Finding velocity of rock when it hits the ground.

Tags: calculus

So, suppose a rock is thrown upward with a speed of $30ft/s$ from the edge of a building $200ft$ above the ground. How would you find the speed of the stone when it hits the ground also assuming acceleration due to gravity is $-32ft/s^2$?

I know that 30ft/s is the initial speed of the stone, 200 is the position at time t=0, and the rock is accelerating at a rate of -32ft/s. I know the kinematic formulas such as $\int a=v(t)$, $\int v(t)=s(t)$
So $s(0)=200$ and so on but I just can not see how all of this fits together for the problem. Any help to set up the initial equations would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice, the maximum height $(h_{max})$ obtained by the rock above the building where the final vertical velocity becomes zero.

Hence, using third equation of motion (moving upwards) $$v_y^2=u_y^2-2gh_{max}$$ setting the corresponding values, we get $$0=(30)^2-2(32)h_{max}\implies h_{max}=\frac{225}{16}$$ 
Now, the rock starts falling down from the highest point at a height $h=h_{max}+200=\frac{225}{16}+200=\frac{3425}{16}$ from the ground & there the initial vertical velocity is zero i.e. $u_y=0$

Hence, using third equation of motion (falling downwards) $$v_y^2=u_y^2+2gh$$ setting the corresponding values, we get $$v_y^2=0+2(32)\left(\frac{3425}{16}\right)$$$$v_y=\sqrt{13700}$$ 
$$\color{red}{v_y=10\sqrt{137}\approx 117.047\ ft/s}$$

Comment: No need to compute $h_{max}$. Just use $v_1^2-v_0^2=2g(-\Delta h)$ once.